# Como apagar linha em Mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém me pode ajudar? Sou iniciante em programação e não estou a conseguir apagar,  através de um botão, nenhuma linha do banco de dados por ID. Já tentei resolver de várias formas mas ele simplesmente assume que está tudo correto mas não apaga a linha definida no banco de dados.

Segue o código:

```
<?php 
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM novidades ORDER BY idGallery DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
echo "SQL statement failed";

} else{
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$idfinal = $row['idGallery'];

echo'
<div class="single-table">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover text-center">
<thead class="text-uppercase">
<tr>
   <th scope="col">Post nº</th>
   <th scope="col">Título</th>
   <th scope="col">Descrição</th>

   <th scope="col">Editar / Apagar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

   <th scope="row">'.$row["idGallery"].'</th>
   <td>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["descGallery"].'</td>';  }}?>
```

O botão:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['apagar'])){
    echo('
    <h5 class="header-title">Tem a certeza que deseja eliminar este post?</h4>
    <form action="includes/novidades-delete.inc.php" method="POST">
    <button name="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Eliminar post</button></form>');
        }else{
        echo "";

        }

        ?>
```

E o código novidades-delete.inc.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    include_once "dbh.inc.php";
  $id = $_POST['idGallery'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM novidades WHERE idGallery='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$result){
    die("Falha ao executar o comando: " . mysqli_error($conn));}
  else{

    header ("Location:/winjoy3/admin/novidades-deleted.php?idGallery=$id");
}}
?>
```

Comment: Onde vc está enviando o `idGallery` no form que chama o `novidades-delete.inc.php`?

Comment: Ahhhh, conseguii!! Só faltava adicionar  <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="'.$row["idGallery"].'"/> e alterar pra $id = $_POST['ids']; Muito obrigada!! :)